# CR3 Format in darktable

Tags: post-processing, raw, darktable, import

Since I can't afford Lightroom, I figured I would use darktable. As I wanted to import my RAW - files (in CR3) I realized that darktable doesn't support them. Is there a way I can still get my RAW - files into darktable?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could use Adobe Camera RAW to convert your files into DNGs. However, there might be drawbacks.

Comment: @KaiMattern There are definitely drawbacks if you ever plan to use an application that uses the data in the "maker notes" section of the EXIF info, such as Canon's own *Digital Photo Professional 4*. Adobe products strip most of the "maker note" section when it converts/exports images.

Comment: Have you considered using Canon's *Digital Photo Professional 4*? It's free and updates can be downloaded from the Canon website in your geographic region. *DPP 4* is fully compatible with all .cr2 and .cr3 files from every Canon camera. It's much better than a lot of folks who have spent 5 minutes with it so they can pretend to know more than everyone else on the internet like to say it is.

Comment: @MichaelC DPP isn't bad but there is no Linux version, and it's a bit too Canon-only (AFAIK there is no correction for my Sigma lenses, for instance).

Comment: RawTherapee has a Linux version and nowadays it has partial support for .CR3. It lacks .CR3 metadata, though, but I suspect that feature is coming soon. But agree, DPP for Canon lenses is better than RawTherapee and darktable.

Comment: @xenoid For the newest Canon cameras when they first come out, it's usually the only one that supports files from that camera for a while.

Comment: Adobe has a free tool to convert many file formats to DNG. It's pretty fast and cross platform. https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/digital-negative.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CR3 raw format is relatively new (introduced with Canon's mirrorless line, and produced by any camera using the DIGIC 8 or later chipsets). As such, not all non-Canon software can support the format yet. It may take some time before your favorite applications support it. Until then, you can use the Canon software that came with your camera.

Looking at the source code repo, it appears that Darktable started recognizing CR3 files (but not loading them) around the v2.6.0 timeframe. Latest version available is v3.1.0, but still apparently does not have full support. Although some other open-source projects (libraw) have finally added some level of support in the last few months.

Comment: Just as with .cr2 files (and .nef or other manufacturers' file formats), applications must have specific information about each camera model. An application could theoretically handle .cr3 files from one camera but not from another until the database is updated to include the newest models.

Answer (score 2):

At the time of writing there are unofficial builds of darktable 3.7 for Windows with CR3 support:

https://discuss.pixls.us/t/current-win10-build-incl-cr3-support/25212/16

If you prefer to use a stable release such as the recent 3.6 you could also use [DNGlab](https://github.com/dnglab/dnglab) instead of Adobe's converter; it is a command line tool to convert CR3 to DNG and runs perfectly on my linux machine.

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for an open source tool to work with CR3 files, and dnglab worked perfectly.

Comment: Do you know how can one install the dnglab? It's a bunch of files that I do not understand!

Comment: To install dnglab simply go to the tags page: https://github.com/dnglab/dnglab/releases/tag/v0.3.1 then choose the zip file for windows (`dnglab-win-x64_v0.3.1.zip`), if you're on ubuntu linux on the other hand download the `.deb` file and install it with `sudo apt install`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks you guys for your answers! I ultimately decided to download Adobe Camera Raw in order to convert them to DNG files as @KaiMattern has pointed out, albeit with drawbacks :D

Answer (score 1):

Good news that the development seems to be ongoing:
https://github.com/darktable-org/darktable/issues/2170